# USSD in ZTE MF833T

Tags: usb-modem, modem, zte

The modem is directly running as USB Etherne and is not detected by Modem Manager GUI.

I have to manage settings in address `http://192.168.0.1/`.

Is it possible to send USSD request in `ZTE MF833T` modem?

[image: modem-settings]

Answer (score 0):

send USSD request in ZTE MF833T modem?
Try This For USSD
http://192.168.0.1/index.html#ussd